# problems using replaceText for special characters: [ ]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to replace "\cite{foo123a}" with "[1]" and backwards. So far I was able to replace text with the following command

```
body.replaceText('.cite{foo}', '[1]');
```

but I did not manage to use

```
body.replaceText('\cite{foo}', '[1]');
body.replaceText('\\cite{foo}', '[1]');
```

Why?

The back conversion I cannot get to work at all

```
body.replaceText('[1]', '\\cite{foo}');
```

this will replace only the "1" not the [ ], this means the [] are interpreted as regex character set, escaping them will not help

```
body.replaceText('\[1\]', '\\cite{foo}');//no effect, still a char set
body.replaceText('/\[1\]/', '\\cite{foo}');//no matches
```

The documentation states

> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

Can I find a full description of what is supported and what not somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Google Apps Script, but this looks like ordinary regular expression troubles.

Your second conversion is not working because the string literal `'\[1\]'` is just the same as `'[1]'`. You want to quote the text `\[1\]` as a string literal, which means `'\\[1\\]'`. Slashes inside of a string literal have no relevant meaning; in that case you have written a pattern which matches the text `/1/`.

Your first conversion is not working because `{...}` denotes a quantifier, not literal braces, so you need `\\\\cite\\{foo\\}`. (The four backslashes are because to match a literal `\` in a regular expression is `\\`, and to make that a string literal it is `\\\\` — two escaped backslashes.)

Comment: You should work with Apps Script regex just like regular javascript. This statement in the documentation is just for "advanced regex usage", so that developers that use those test their regexes beforehand. Kevin explanation nailed the problem.

Comment: thank you and i will try this tomorrow and let you know if it worked. I work with regular expressions for a long time but this is my start with regexes in js and it is different again o_O

Comment: thanks it worked, this super escaping is still quite confusing, but I will learn :D

Comment: some small correction: in the answer it should say '\\\[1\\\]'

Comment: @select Thanks! You see the problem :)  — the layered syntaxes are systematic, but it's hard to think about how they should be applied. This is why languages often provide regular expressions as language syntax, (you can write `/\[1\]/` in Perl or JavaScript, without the extra string quoting) or a string syntax which eschews backslash escapes in favor of no escapes or a different escape character ("raw strings" `r"..."` in Python, for example).