# Programmatically removing newlines inside Google Documents

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, newline

I wrote a trivial google apps script that runs thru a google document to divide pieces of text. Now, the text that my code need to divide seems to include newlines.

My problem is that I just don't understand how to remove these programmatically (I tried: `mydoc.replaceText("/\n/","");` and `mydoc.replaceText(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");` plus other similar variations with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problems using replaceText for special characters: \[ \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979809/problems-using-replacetext-for-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but maybe something like this works for you? replaces whitespace with single spaces

```
mydoc.replaceText("/\s/"," ");
```